# dotnet run --ulrs on a systemctl service

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, systemd, services, systemctl

I need to run `dotnet run --urls https://0.0.0.0:443` to run a dotnet core API, but I want to turn that into a service, right now I have this:

```bsh
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mdvAPI.service

[Unit]
Description=Dotnet API MDV

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/g67Admin/projeto_integrador_grupo67/mdv/
ExecStart=dotnet run --urls https://0.0.0.0:443

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and when I try to start it I get this:

```bsh
sudo systemctl start mdvAPI.service

Failed to start mdvAPI.service: Unit mdvAPI.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See system logs and 'systemctl status mdvAPI.service' for details.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I developed the following system service script:

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=Whatever you want

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/my/project
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet run --urls https://0.0.0.0:443
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```